# Installing an HP Deskjet 3630 printer

Tags: software-installation, printing, hp, hplip

I am trying to install a HP Deskjet 3630 printer, on Ubuntu 20.04 (64-bit, Gnome version 3.36.8). I downloaded and installed HPLIP version 3.20.3.  The printer is connected by a USB cable (I cannot seem to connect it via wifi).

In settings I see I have three printers:

- Desk-jet 3630 (which is the default printer)
- Desk-jet-series 9994A0 (if I try to delete it, it reappears)
- Desk-jet-series CN66R3HQ250658 (if I try to delete it, it reappears)

If I go into HP Device Manager and click on the printer control I see HP Deskjet 3630 listed but with a red cross on it. I click the Stop printer and then Start printer and all seems fine, but when I click on print in a document I get the error messages stating communication error. I'm not sure where it's going wrong.

I just found on HP Manager a little hammer. Clicking on it gives me this terminal report.

```
/usr/share/hplip/check.py:685: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if 'getfacl' not in g and '' is not g and 'file' not in g:

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.21.2)
Self Diagnse Utility and Healing Utility ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.21.2)
Self Diagnse Utility and Healing Utility ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

-Gtk-Message: 15:12:53.809: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
 
Checking for Deprecated items....
No Deprecated items are found

Checking for HPLIP updates....

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.21.2)
HPLIP upgrade latest version ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Latest version of HPLIP is already installed.

Checking for Dependencies....

---------------
| SYSTEM INFO |
---------------

 Kernel: 5.8.0-43-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 5 09:57:56 UTC 2021 GNU/Linux
 Host: MCPC
 Proc: 5.8.0-43-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 5 09:57:56 UTC 2021 GNU/Linux
 Distribution: 12 20.04
 Bitness: 64 bit

-----------------------
| HPLIP CONFIGURATION |
-----------------------

HPLIP-Version: HPLIP 3.21.2
HPLIP-Home: /usr/share/hplip
HPLIP-Installation: Auto installation is supported for ubuntu distro  20.04 version 

Current contents of '/etc/hp/hplip.conf' file:
# hplip.conf.  Generated from hplip.conf.in by configure.

[hplip]
version=3.21.2

[dirs]
home=/usr/share/hplip
run=/var/run
ppd=/usr/share/ppd/HP
ppdbase=/usr/share/ppd
doc=/usr/share/doc/hplip-3.21.2
html=/usr/share/doc/hplip-3.21.2
icon=/usr/share/applications
cupsbackend=/usr/lib/cups/backend
cupsfilter=/usr/lib/cups/filter
drv=/usr/share/cups/drv/hp
bin=/usr/bin
apparmor=/etc/apparmor.d
# Following values are determined at configure time and cannot be changed.
[configure]
network-build=yes
libusb01-build=no
pp-build=no
gui-build=yes
scanner-build=yes
fax-build=yes
dbus-build=yes
cups11-build=no
doc-build=yes
shadow-build=no
hpijs-install=no
foomatic-drv-install=no
foomatic-ppd-install=no
foomatic-rip-hplip-install=no
hpcups-install=yes
cups-drv-install=yes
cups-ppd-install=no
internal-tag=3.21.2
restricted-build=no
ui-toolkit=qt5
qt3=no
qt4=no
qt5=yes
policy-kit=no
lite-build=no
udev_sysfs_rules=no
hpcups-only-build=no
hpijs-only-build=no
apparmor_build=yes
class-driver=no

Current contents of '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state' file:
Plugins are not installed. Could not access file: No such file or directory

Current contents of '~/.hplip/hplip.conf' file:
[upgrade]
notify_upgrade = true
last_upgraded_time = 1613830932
pending_upgrade_time = 0
latest_available_version = 3.17.10

[installation]
date_time = 02/20/21 15:12:54
version = 3.21.2

 <Package-name>        <Package-Desc>      <Required/Optional> <Min-Version> <Installed-Version> <Status>   <Comment>

-------------------------
| External Dependencies |
-------------------------

 cups                 CUPS - Common Unix Printing System                           REQUIRED        1.1             2.3.1           OK         'CUPS Scheduler is running'
 gs                   GhostScript - PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer REQUIRED        7.05            9.50            OK         -
Gtk-Message: 15:13:02.723: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 15:13:02.748: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
 xsane                xsane - Graphical scanner frontend for SANE                  OPTIONAL        0.9             0.999           OK         -
 scanimage            scanimage - Shell scanning program                           OPTIONAL        1.0             1.0.29          OK         -
 dbus                 DBus - Message bus system                                    REQUIRED        -               1.12.16         OK         -
 policykit            PolicyKit - Administrative policy framework                  OPTIONAL        -               0.105           OK         -
 network              network -wget                                                OPTIONAL        -               1.20.3          OK         -
 avahi-utils          avahi-utils                                                  OPTIONAL        -               0.7             OK         -

------------------------
| General Dependencies |
------------------------

 libjpeg              libjpeg - JPEG library                                       REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 cups-devel           CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files    REQUIRED        -               2.3.1           OK         -
 cups-image           CUPS image - CUPS image development files                    REQUIRED        -               2.3.1           OK         -
 libpthread           libpthread - POSIX threads library                           REQUIRED        -               b'2.31'         OK         -
 libusb               libusb - USB library                                         REQUIRED        -               1.0             OK         -
 sane                 SANE - Scanning library                                      REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 sane-devel           SANE - Scanning library development files                    REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 libavahi-dev         libavahi-dev                                                 REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 libnetsnmp-devel     libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files REQUIRED        5.0.9           5.8             OK         -
 libcrypto            libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library                    REQUIRED        -               1.1.1           OK         -
 python3X             Python 2.2 or greater - Python programming language          REQUIRED        2.2             3.8.5           OK         -
 python3-notify2      Python libnotify - Python bindings for the libnotify Desktop notifications OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
 python3-pyqt5-dbus   PyQt 5 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt5                         OPTIONAL        5.0             5.14.1          OK         -
 python3-pyqt5        PyQt 5- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x)         REQUIRED        5.0             5.14.1          OK         -
 python3-dbus         Python DBus - Python bindings for DBus                       REQUIRED        0.80.0          1.2.16          OK         -
 python3-xml          Python XML libraries                                         REQUIRED        -               2.2.9           OK         -
 python3-devel        Python devel - Python development files                      REQUIRED        2.2             3.8.5           OK         -
 python3-pil          PIL - Python Imaging Library (required for commandline scanning with hp-scan) OPTIONAL        -               7.0.0           OK         -
 python3-reportlab    Reportlab - PDF library for Python                           OPTIONAL        2.0             3.5.34          OK         -

--------------
| COMPILEDEP |
--------------

 libtool              libtool - Library building support services                  REQUIRED        -               2.4.6           OK         -
 gcc                  gcc - GNU Project C and C++ Compiler                         REQUIRED        -               9.3.0           OK         -
 make                 make - GNU make utility to maintain groups of programs       REQUIRED        3.0             4.2.1           OK         

---------------------
| Python Extentions |
---------------------

 cupsext              CUPS-Extension                                               REQUIRED        -               3.21.2          OK         -
 hpmudext             IO-Extension                                                 REQUIRED        -               3.21.2          OK         -

----------------------
| Scan Configuration |
----------------------

 hpaio                HPLIP-SANE-Backend                                           REQUIRED        -               3.21.2          OK         'hpaio found in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf'
 scanext              Scan-SANE-Extension                                          REQUIRED        -               3.21.2          OK         -

------------------------------
| DISCOVERED SCANNER DEVICES |
------------------------------

device `hpaio:/usb/DeskJet_3630_series?serial=CN66R3HQ250658' is a Hewlett-Packard DeskJet_3630_series all-in-one
device `hpaio:/net/deskjet_3630_series?ip=192.168.1.118&queue=false' is a Hewlett-Packard deskjet_3630_series all-in-one
device `escl:https://192.168.1.118:443' is a ESCL HP DeskJet 3630 series [9994A0] SSL flatbed scanner
device `escl:http://127.0.0.1:60000' is a ESCL DeskJet 3630 series [CN66R3HQ250658] flatbed scanner
device `escl:http://192.168.1.118:8080' is a ESCL HP DeskJet 3630 series [9994A0] flatbed scanner

--------------------------
| DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |
--------------------------

  Device URI                        Model                 
  --------------------------------  ----------------------
  hp:/usb/DeskJet_3630_series?seri  HP DeskJet 3630 series
  al=CN66R3HQ250658                                       

---------------------------------
| INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES |
---------------------------------
 
DeskJet-3630
------------
Type: Printer
Device URI: hp:/usb/DeskJet_3630_series?serial=CN66R3HQ250658
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/DeskJet-3630.ppd
warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/DeskJet-3630.ppd ppd file
PPD Description: 
Printer status: printer DeskJet-3630 is idle.  enabled since Sat 20 Feb 2021 15:03:51 GMT
error: Unable to communicate with device (code=12): hp:/usb/DeskJet_3630_series?serial=CN66R3HQ250658
error: Device not found
error: Communication status: Failed

--------------
| PERMISSION |
--------------

USB             DeskJet-3630                   Required        -        -        OK       Node:'/dev/bus/usb/002/006' Perm:'  root  lp rw- rw- rw- rw- r--'
 
Checking Permissions....

Checking for Configured Queues....
warning: Fail to read ppd=/etc/cups/ppd/DeskJet-3630.ppd file
warning: Insufficient permission to access file /etc/cups/ppd/DeskJet-3630.ppd
warning: Could not complete Queue(s) configuration check

Checking for HP Properitery Plugin's....
No plug-in printers are configured.

Checking for Printer Status....
error: 'DeskJet-3630' Printer is either Powered-OFF or Failed to communicate.
Turn On Printer and re-run hp-doctor

Diagnose completed...

More information on Troubleshooting,How-To's and Support is available on http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html

Please close this terminal manually.
```

Comment: You have to set up printers and print queues through CUPS (Common Unix Printing System) at `http://localhost:631`. Also read `man lpstat lpadmin`. Read some of `man -k cups`.

Comment: Sorry, as I said I am new to Linux and the page you sent to me made no sense to me

Comment: Hey @MarkCullen ! Please paste the output of `dpkg -l hplip` in your question by [edit]ing your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Switch off printer.
2. Do `sudo apt purge ippusbxd`
3. Switch printer on.

Success?

Comment: Tried that got the following, Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-front end  open 13: (Permission denied) Unable to aquire the dpkg front end lock ( var/lib/dpkg/lock-front end) you are root ?

Comment: @Mark Cullen I have correctd my answer to include `sudo`.